# Is it possible to run a command from Cygwin, into a Git Bash terminal, with arguments?

Tags: linux, terminal, cygwin, git-bash

I haven't been able to find a similar question, but I can't imagine this is an issue that comes up too much.

At my workplace I've decided to switch over to a full Linux experience by using Cygwin, over what I was previously using, Git Bash.

The only slight drawback is that we have a script written in Ruby that deploys changes to our site. I can run this from my Git Bash terminal no problem, but not Cygwin as there doesn't seem to be a Ruby installation on here. I've learned about sending standard output to other terminal windows, but I've only been successful when both terminals have been the same shell.

What I'd like to do is the following:
 1. Type a command into Cygwin that opens a Git Bash terminal and automatically runs ./deploy.sh on that Git Bash terminal upon opening.
 2. If possible, also pass in an argument in the same command, that the script expects upon running. (In this case it's whether we want to deploy to our staging or production server).

Is this possible? So far I can get what looks to be a Git Bash terminal to open and prompt me for the server, but when I enter it, it does not work. I get an error with regards to a command within the script not being found. Thing is, running this same ./deploy.sh script in a Git Bash terminal that I open myself works perfectly as it always has. The Git Bash terminal that is being opened by Cygwin does not appear to have all of the capabilities of a Git Bash terminal I open 'the normal way'.

The command I am running so far from Cygwin is as follows:
/cygdrive/c/'Program Files'/Git/git-bash.exe "./deploy.sh"

I understand there is probably a way of getting this to work by installing Ruby via Cygwin but I'd like to mess around with my work environment as little as possible in case I somehow affect my ability to deploy my work... and besides, Git Bash definitely runs this script without an issue so I can't see why I would need a duplicate installation.

Many thanks!

Comment: Would it work if you run `bash.exe` from the `bin` directory like `/cygdrive/c/'Program Files'/Git/bin/bash.exe -c '~/deploy.sh "$@"' bash arg1 arg2`. I don't have cygwin, but I can call it like that from WSL.

Comment: That does run the script successfully within the same Cygwin terminal... but now I'm getting an SSH authentication error that I don't get running from a separate Git Bash terminal...

Comment: Again, it's like the Git Bash shells just don't have the same behaviour when being called from Cygwin. It's so close though! You definitely got around the first main problem I had but now it seems strange that authentication is fine from a normally opened Git Bash terminal, but not one called from a Cygwin command.

Comment: Install Ruby package from Cygwin setup.  https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/ruby.html

Comment: There's honestly no good reason to be mixing up "Git Bash" with Cygwin.  If you want to use Cygwin you can install Ruby in Cygwin, as well as git.  I don't fully understand your question (maybe some screenshots would help) but I think you are vastly overcomplicating things for yourself.  It sounds like there's nothing you're trying to do that you can't just do with Cygwin.

Comment: You might also look into the `cygstart` command which is useful for starting non-Cygwin Windows executables as though they were started directly from the Windows shell (i.e. `explorer.exe`) as opposed to from a shell in Cygwin.

Comment: That's great, thanks